# Cordova error due to 8.0 The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I get the following error when installing a plugin.

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-canvas" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-canvas': TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: Uh oh!
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1155:7)
    at install (Users/xx/yy/zz/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:61:29)
    at ActionStack.process (/Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ActionStack.js:56:25)
    at PluginManager.doOperation (/Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:114:20)
    at PluginManager.addPlugin (/Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:144:17)
    at /Users/xx/yy/zz/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:212:74
    at _fulfilled (/Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/xx/yy/zz/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
Uh oh!
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

> cordova --version
>   8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

seems in
pluginHandlers.js `line18` imports module

```
var path = require('path');
```

But on `line 61`

```
'resource-file': {
        install: function (obj, plugin, project, options) {
            var dest = path.join('app', 'src', 'main', obj.target);
```

treats it as a string. How do I fix this issue?

Any resource-file tags like below in plugin.xml prevents the plugin from installing.

```
<resource-file src="src/android/app/src/main/assets/FAsolid.ttf" target-dir="assets/FAsolid.ttf"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

i had similuar issues and turns out i hade to replace

```
<resource-file src="..." target-dir="assets/..."/>
```

to

```
<source-file src="..." target-dir="..."/>
```

Comment: I wanted to write a resource file without a src. I had to use config-file :S



    `<config-file target="res/values/strings.xml" parent="/*">`

Answer (score 0):

From my findings this exception can be thrown whenever there are problems with permissions to folders npm is managing and there are numerous locations on ubuntu: `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/share`, `~/.npm`, `~/.cordova` and even more. If you would execute the build in the environment itself there is a chance to get the relevant folder that lacks the permission.

Yet, after playing with it a lot I found out that the actual problem is with `util.js` file under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js` and the problem was with the following line: `global_config_path = path.join(HOME, '.cordova');`

This code executes only in case `CORDOVA_HOME` environment variable does not exist. So I've just added it: `export CORDOVA_HOME="~/.cordova"` and the exception was gone.
Hope it'll help someone.